# sum of column php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Trying to figure out why I am unable to grab the sum of a column.  In mysql column is Decimal(65,2) - not sure if that causes any conflict, and $ signs have been removed as they were initally there from csv import export but ran replace and all are clear.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ContactId, Date, First_Name, Last_Name, Referral_Partner,
Sale_Total, SUM(Sale_Total) AS sum_ttl 
    FROM PTLS1117v2 
     WHERE Referral_Partner = '$refpart' 
      AND Date BETWEEN '$pdate' AND '$pdate2'";
```

Comment: What output are you getting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: I'm getting the full row output off all the data itself, but getting no response when trying to display the sum, and have tried various methods for displaying it.  Just expecting the sum of the Sale_Total column to be able to display all purchases for dates, and referral partners selected. 

Sale_Total displays just fine, but not the SUM, even tried to display just that alone, and with just the ContactId, but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

First, a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `t` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xyzyy',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Populate it:

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into t(s,t) values ('10.00','xyz'),('20.00','xyz'),('30.00','xyz'),('40.00','xyz'),('50.00','xyz');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into t(s,t) values ('60.00','abc'),('70.00','abc'),('80.00','abc'),('90.00','abc'),('100.00','abc');
Query OK, 5 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select s,t from t;
+--------+-----+
| s      | t   |
+--------+-----+
| 10.00  | xyz |
| 20.00  | xyz |
| 30.00  | xyz |
| 40.00  | xyz |
| 50.00  | xyz |
| 60.00  | abc |
| 70.00  | abc |
| 80.00  | abc |
| 90.00  | abc |
| 100.00 | abc |
+--------+-----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using `DISTINCT` I get this:

```
MariaDB [test]> select distinct s,t,sum(s) from t where t='abc';
+-------+------+--------+
| s     | t    | sum(s) |
+-------+------+--------+
| 60.00 | abc  | 400.00 |
+-------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you're trying to retrieve all rows for a specific `Referral_Partner`, with a grand total, you're going to have to use two queries - one for the data, one for the sum. Alternatively, calculate the total as you retrieve rows from the table

Comment: Sounds good.  Tried to run as a separate query prior to posting here and a standalone simple one without DISTINCT thinking that was the issue - but no luck, will play around with it more.  Thanks!